# ng-repeat custom orderBy function does not correctly sort table rows that includes empty rows

Tags: angularjs

I have a table that has a mixture of rows with data and rows without. My idea later on is to be able to edit those empty rows to add data.

```
   <table>
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th ng-click="sortField='name';reverse=!reverse">
               Name
               <i class="fas fa-chevron-down" ng-show="sortField=='name'&&reverse"></i>
               <i class="fas fa-chevron-up" ng-show="sortField=='name'&&!reverse"></i>
            </th>
            <th ng-click="sortField='age';reverse=!reverse">
               Age
               <i class="fas fa-chevron-down" ng-show="sortField=='age'&&reverse"></i>
               <i class="fas fa-chevron-up" ng-show="sortField=='age'&&!reverse"></i>
            </th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr ng-repeat="user in users | orderBy:sortBy:reverse">
            <td>{{user.name}}</td>
            <td>{{user.age}}</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
```

Currently I am trying to find a way of sorting my table data with whichever heading has been clicked but always put the empty rows at the bottom.

```
$scope.sortBy = function(element) {
    if (element[$scope.sortField] != "") {
        if (!$scope.reverse) {
            return element[$scope.sortField];
        } 
    }
}
```

I have managed to do that but the order is not corrected when sorted.

Here is an example I created:

https://jsfiddle.net/os5pqLt7/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fake it by returning some arbitrary value when the field you are sorting on does not have a value. Here's something you can try replacing your `$scope.sortBy` function with:

```
$scope.sortBy = function(element) {
  if (!$scope.reverse) {
    if ($scope.sortField === 'name') {
      return element[$scope.sortField] || 'ZZZZZ';
    }
    return element[$scope.sortField];
  }
  else {
    if ($scope.sortField === 'age') {
      return element[$scope.sortField] || -1;
    }
    return element[$scope.sortField];
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Works like a charm! Thanks a bunch

Comment: Is there any way to prevent it from running the sortBy function when I am entering data? I have updated the JSFIDDLE to reflect what I am trying to do

Comment: Yes, sort of...you can use the `ng-model-options` directive and either debounce or only update on blur. This will prevent the model from being updated real time as the user is typing which I think is what you're trying to avoid.